# Java Jasper Report Export PDF failed

Tags: java, groovy, jasper-reports

I'm having trouble exporting the PDF to get help.

I ran it in a dev environment and it ran fine, but when I went to production (using WebSphere and Tomcat server) it crashed with PDF, excel still running fine.

Here is the code:

```
 fileName+= DateProc.getYYYYMMDDHHMMSSString(DateProc.createTimestamp()) + ".pdf"
JRPdfExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();
exporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(jasperPrint));
ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(os));
println("exporter:" + exporter)
exporter.exportReport(); --> running here stop, do not shoot out errors
println("done")
render downloadFileService.downloadReport(fileName, os.toByteArray()) //process download file
```

I tried the following code also failed:

```
    fileName+= DateProc.getYYYYMMDDHHMMSSString(DateProc.createTimestamp()) + ".pdf"
byte[] outArray = JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdf(jasperPrint);
render downloadFileService.downloadReport(fileName, outArray)



java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter.setRgbTransparencyBlending(Z)V 
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportReportToStream(JRPdfExporter.java:480) 
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportReport(JRPdfExporter.java:379) 
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(JasperExportManager.java:122) 
ReportServlet.processRequest(ReportServlet.java:104) 
ReportServlet.doGet(ReportServlet.java:142) 
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:690) 
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
```

I use the following libraries:
- iText-2.1.7.js2.jar
- itext-4.2.0.jar
- itextpdf-5.5.0.jar
- jasperreports-5.6.0.jar
- jasperreports-fonts-5.6.0.jar
- jasperreports-javaflow-5.6.0.jar

Thanks

Comment: What is the error? At what line do you have it? Please edit your question and add the error info.

Comment: @TriệuVănHiển `I tried the following code also failed:` - You should post stacktrace

Comment: I have added the log. Please support me. Thanks :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jasper report: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter.setRgbTransparencyBlending](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53111760/jasper-report-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-com-lowagie-text-pdf-pdfwriter-setrg)