# Jasper report: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter.setRgbTransparencyBlending

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I run in Tomcat, jasper report crashed with PDF, excel still running fine.

```
JRPdfExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();
exporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(jasperPrint));
ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(os));
exporter.exportReport();
```

And error shot out:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter.setRgbTransparencyBlending(Z)V 
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportReportToStream(JRPdfExporter.java:480) 
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportReport(JRPdfExporter.java:379) 
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(JasperExportManager.java:122) 
ReportServlet.processRequest(ReportServlet.java:104) 
ReportServlet.doGet(ReportServlet.java:142) 
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:690) 
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
```

I use the following libraries: 
- iText-2.1.7.js2.jar 
- itext-4.2.0.jar 
- itextpdf-5.5.0.jar 
- jasperreports-5.6.0.jar 
- jasperreports-fonts-5.6.0.jar 
- jasperreports-javaflow-5.6.0.jar

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Your itext version is old as compared to jasperreports version. Please use the latest version. Note that the artifactId and/or groupId have changed:-

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
    <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
    <version>5.5.13</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

After using the latest version 5.5.13, I checked that the war file after the build file has version text-2.0.8 and caused errors. So how to do to fix?

Here is build.grade file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.grails:grails-gradle-plugin:$grailsVersion"
        classpath "gradle.plugin.com.craigburke.gradle:karma-gradle:1.4.3"
        classpath "com.craigburke.gradle:client-dependencies:1.1.1"
        classpath "org.grails.plugins:angular-scaffolding:1.0.0"
        classpath "org.grails.plugins:hibernate5:6.0.0"
        classpath "com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-gradle:2.11.1"
        classpath "org.grails.plugins:views-gradle:1.1.0"
        classpath 'org.grails.plugins:quartz:2.0.6'
        classpath 'jcifs:jcifs:1.3.17'
        classpath 'com.hierynomus:smbj:0.7.0'
    }
}

ext.springSecurityRestVersion = '2.0.0.M2'

version "1.0.0"
group "m1t.ptud"

apply plugin:"eclipse"
apply plugin:"idea"
apply plugin:"war"
apply plugin:"org.grails.grails-web"
apply plugin:"org.grails.grails-gsp"
apply plugin:"com.craigburke.karma"
apply plugin:"com.craigburke.client-dependencies"
apply plugin:"asset-pipeline"
apply plugin:"org.grails.plugins.views-json"

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.grails:grails-bom:$grailsVersion"
    }
    applyMavenExclusions false
}

grails {
    pathingJar = true
}

dependencies {
    assets "com.craigburke.angular:angular-template-asset-pipeline:2.3.0"
    assets "com.craigburke.angular:angular-annotate-asset-pipeline:2.4.0"
    assets "com.craigburke:js-closure-wrap-asset-pipeline:1.2.0"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure"
    compile "org.grails:grails-core"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-url-mappings"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-rest"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-codecs"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-interceptors"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-services"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-datasource"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-databinding"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-async"
    compile "org.grails:grails-web-boot"
    compile "org.grails:grails-logging"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:cache"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-gsp"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:angular-scaffolding:1.0.1"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:hibernate5"
    compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.1.1.Final"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:views-json"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:views-json-templates"
//    compile 'org.grails.plugins:spring-security-cas:3.1.0'
    /*compile "net.sf.jasperreports:jasperreports:5.6.0"
    compile "net.sf.jasperreports:jasperreports-fonts:5.6.0"*/
    console "org.grails:grails-console"
    profile "org.grails.profiles:angular"

    runtime "com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-grails:2.11.1"
    testCompile "org.grails:grails-plugin-testing"
    testCompile "org.grails.plugins:geb"
    testCompile "org.grails:grails-datastore-rest-client"
    testRuntime "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-htmlunit-driver:2.47.1"
    testRuntime "net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit:2.18"
    // added
    compile ("com.hazelcast:hazelcast-hibernate5:1.0") {
        exclude group: "com.hazelcast"
    }
    compile "org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:3.1.1"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:spring-security-rest:${springSecurityRestVersion}"
    compile 'org.grails.plugins:spring-security-ldap:3.0.1'
    compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-csv:2.7.0"
    compile "com.hazelcast:hazelcast-all:3.7.1"
    compile "com.sun.mail:javax.mail:1.5.6"
    compile "net.sf.jt400:jt400:9.1"
    compile 'org.grails.plugins:excel-import:3.0.0.RC2'
    compile "org.grails.plugins:excel-export:2.0.3"
    compile 'com.jameskleeh:excel-builder:0.3.0'
    compile "org.grails.plugins:mail:2.0.0.RC1"

    compile "com.jcraft:jsch:0.1.49"
    compile 'org.grails.plugins:quartz:2.0.6'
    compile 'org.grails.plugins:quartz-monitor:1.3'
    compile 'jcifs:jcifs:1.3.17'
    compile 'com.hierynomus:smbj:0.7.0'
    compile group: 'com.itextpdf', name: 'itextpdf', version: '5.5.13'

//    compile 'org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:jar:3.17'

//    compile 'net.sf.jasperreports:jasperreports:6.4.0'
//    compile 'net.sf.jasperreports:jasperreports-fonts:6.0.0'
//    compile 'org.grails.plugins:jasper:2.0.0.RC1'


    assets 'com.bertramlabs.plugins:less-asset-pipeline:2.11.1'
    assets 'com.bertramlabs.plugins:sass-asset-pipeline:2.11.1'


    compile fileTree(dir: 'lib', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile(project(':ast'))
}
clientDependencies {
    npm {
        'angular'('1.5.x', into: 'angular') {
            include 'angular.js'
        }
        'angular-mocks'('1.5.x', into: 'angular') {
            include 'angular-mocks.js'
        }
        'angular-resource'('1.5.x', into: 'angular') {
            include 'angular-resource.js'
        }
        'angular-ui-bootstrap'('1.3.x', into: 'angular') {
            include 'ui-bootstrap-tpls.js'
        }
        'angular-ui-router'('0.2.x', into: 'angular', from: 'release') {
            include 'angular-ui-router.js'
        }
        'bootstrap-sass'('3.3.x', into: 'bootstrap', from: 'assets') {
            include 'fonts/**'
            include 'stylesheets/**'
        }
        'font-awesome'('4.6.x', into: 'font-awesome') {
            include 'scss/**'
            include 'fonts/**'
        }
        'angular-translate'('2.12.x', into: 'angular') {
            include 'angular-translate.js'
        }

        'angular-translate-loader-static-files'('2.12.x', into: 'angular') {
            include 'angular-translate-loader-static-files.js'
        }
        'angular-translate-handler-log'('2.12.x', into: 'angular') {
            include 'angular-translate-handler-log.js'
        }
        'ngstorage'('0.3.x', into: 'angular') {
            include 'ngStorage.js'
        }
        'alertifyjs'('1.8.x', into: 'alertify', from: 'build') {
            include '**'
        }
        'ng-file-upload'('12.2.x', into: 'angular', from: 'dist') {
            include 'ng-file-upload-all.js'
        }

    }
    bower {
        'angular-smart-table'('2.1.x', into: 'angular', from: 'dist') {
            include 'smart-table.js'
        }
        'angular-ui-select'('0.19.x', into: 'angular/select', from: 'dist') {
            include 'select.js'
            include 'select.css'
        }
        'simple-line-icons'('2.4.x', into: 'simple-line-icons') {
            include 'fonts/*'
            include 'scss/*'
        }
        'angular-loading-bar'('0.9.x',into: 'angular/loading', from: 'build') {
            include 'loading-bar.js'
            include 'loading-bar.css'
        }
        'angular-animate'('1.5.x',into: 'angular') {
            include 'angular-animate.js'
        }
        'angular-sanitize'('1.5.x', into: 'angular') {
            include 'angular-sanitize.js'
        }
        'angular-validation'('1.4.x', into: 'angular', from: 'dist') {
            include 'angular-validation.js'
            include 'angular-validation-rule.js'
        }
        'ng-currency'('0.*', into: 'angular', from: 'dist') {
            include 'ng-currency.js'
        }
        'blob-polyfill'('1.0.x', into: 'blob-polyfill') {
            include 'Blob.js'
        }
        'file-saver'('1.3.x', into: 'file-saver') {
            include 'FileSaver.js'
        }
    }
}

karma {
    dependencies(['karma-wrap-preprocessor'])

    profile 'angularJS'

    preprocessors = [
        'grails-app/assets/javascripts/**/*.js': ['wrap']
    ]

    wrapPreprocessor = [
        template: "(function () { 'use strict';  <%= contents %> })()"
    ]
}

assets {
    minifyJs = false
    minifyCss = false
    enableSourceMaps = true
    enableGzip = true
    includes = ['**/m1t.ptud.js', '**/application.css']
    excludes = ['**/*.js', '**/*.html', '**/*.*css']
    developmentRuntime=true
}
```